# Return a Document in a method

Tags: java, return-value, default-value

When returning an Object (as `Document`) in a method and creation isn't `implements AutoCloseable` I often see declaring first line the object and returning it at the end:

```
public Document myMethod() {
 Document document = null
 try {
    document  = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    //...work on document 
 } catch(Exception e) {
   // Handle Exception
 }
 return document;
}
```

It seems that the following rule is always correct, create and return inside try clause (and possible to extract this code to method )

```
public Document myMethod() {

 try {
    Document document  = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    //...work on document
    return document;
 } catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle Exception
 }
 return null;
}
```

Am I missing anything? (you can relate to cases where `null` can be a default value but it's less significant)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. All I can say is that the second option is probably safer, since if there is an exception in creating the document, `null` is returned instead of a possibly broken/unfinished document.

Comment: @kajacx it's an answer, just want to know I can always/almost always change such methods

Comment: Please don't catch Exception, but a specific one.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker yes, please ignore the Exception, I tried to generalized the specific question, in specific code it's `ParserConfigurationException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having only a single `return` statement at the end of a method was once taught as a style guideline to promote readability.  Perhaps merely out of habit, it is still my preference when working on projects that don't have an established style to the contrary.

However, the only cases where it really makes a difference are long, complex methods that should probably be decomposed anyway.

Given good coding practices (e.g. test appropriate unit test coverage, so you know you're returning the right thing under any relevant condition, including exceptions) this really is just a matter of team/project preference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one follow up, isn't try with resources feature introduce a new way for creating and handling objects inside try block over creating and using it outside block?

Comment: The question does not address try-with-resources syntax.  If you'd like to ask a question about such syntax, feel free to post it as a question.  (Questions don't belong in comments, as this buries information in a hard-to-read format.  And it is not advisable to edit your existing question in a way that changes its scope, as this makes existing answers less useful to future searchers.)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the 2nd code block has a `catch(Exception e`) clause, they are effectively equivalent.

For this code, it's a matter of preference whether one wants to

- Initialize the variable to null outside the `try` block and returning the object at the end
- Declare the variable inside the try block and return null at the end

If there was a case where you wanted to operate on the `Object o` outside the try block, then you'd need to initialize the variable outside the block, so that it's appropriately scoped and available.

Some coders adhere to a convention where they try to only have 1 return statement per method.  (I'm not one of them).

For what you're asking, it seems to be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I've added `catch(Exception e)` to first clause, Isn't extracting a inner method is more prominent option?

Comment: Both approaches are perfectly appropriate.  Honestly, I can't say which approach is most prominent.  You'll see both approaches taken in all kinds of codebases, and it's fine either way.  The only difference is the variable scope if one needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers/comments here suggest that there is no real difference between the 2 aproachs and that they are functinaly the same, and it's just a matter of preference.

This is not true, there is a very important functional difference. If an exception occures in the `//...work on document`, the first solution will return an unfinished or possibly broken document (unless the is `return null;` in the `// Handle Exception` block), whereas the second option will return null.

I would therefore recommend using option 2), as it reduces the risk of a broken document being returned from the method which you might not notice right away and could lead to problems elsewhere, whereas returning `null` is a clearcut indication that something went wrong in your method.

Comment: "If an exception occures in the //...work on document, the first solution will return an unfinished or possibly broken document ".  No, it will run the exception handler, which will decide what should be returned.  Style is not dictated by the assumption that the coder doesn't know how to code, and the issue of knowing what's returned in an exception case is addressed by unit test coverage regardless.

Comment: First, you probably didn't read the "(unless the is return null; in the // Handle Exception block)" portion of my answer, and second, "knowing what's returned in an exception case is addressed by unit test coverage regardless." that assumes there is a test case for exception being raised in the "//...work on document" block, which might not be the case, maybe the only test with an exception is when it is thrown by the "docFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();" statement, or maybe there is not even a unit test for this method at all.

Comment: "That assumes there is a test case for..."  Yes, in determining good coding practices, I assume people will follow good coding practices.  Good day.